# CEF - Get html in std::string

Tags: c++, chromium-embedded

Can someone please suggest an example for CEF - how to load an HTML page and put it in std::string?

I looked at the documentation of the CEF, but unfortunately I could not figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the function you can use: https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/src/7b0bb931b19cb192b1a0cb1838e639a4ad9fb6e3/include/cef_frame.h#lines-123

```
#include "include/cef_frame.h"

///
// Retrieve this frame's HTML source as a string sent to the specified
// visitor.
///
/*--cef()--*/
virtual void GetSource(CefRefPtr<CefStringVisitor> visitor) = 0;
```